# How to get data from service?

Tags: angular

There is a varaible inside service:

```
  public currentLayers = new Map<TreeNode, RegistryLayerItemGeneric[]>();
```

I fill this variable after response:

```
  this.registryDataSource
      .getRegistryPolygon(registry.Id, currentScale)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.currentLayers = this.hardPrepare(response);
      });
```

How to get this data inside component to render in template?

I tried to get variable directly from service:

```
  public get currentLayers() {
    return this.registryLayers.currentLayers;
  }
```

Then to use in template:

```
<div *ngFor="let layer of currentLayers | keyvalue"></div>
```

But this approach renders template each time when user focuses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return an observable from the service and leverage [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in the html template:

In your service:

```
public currentLayers = AsyncSubject<TreeNode, RegistryLayerItemGeneric[]> = new AsyncSubject();


.
.
.

 this.registryDataSource
      .getRegistryPolygon(registry.Id, currentScale)
      .subscribe((response) => {

        this.currentLayers.next(this.hardPrepare(response));
      });
```

template:

```
<div *ngFor="let layer of registryDataSource.currentLayers | async | keyvalue"></div>
```

This way you'll get the benefits of async pipe: automatic change detection and unsubscribe on component destruction.
And also no redundant code in component.ts.

---

Notice that for encapsulation it'll be better to return an Observable from the service and not AsyncSubject.

In your service you should do:

```
public _currentLayers = AsyncSubject<TreeNode, RegistryLayerItemGeneric[]> = new AsyncSubject();

public get currentLayers(): Observable<TreeNode, RegistryLayerItemGeneric[]> {
    return _currentLayers.asObservable()
}
```